# Invalid control source in MS Access while linking data by foreign keys

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I need to create form which holds data `Country.country_name` for current `Supplier.supplier_id` of current `Product` record. A product has **FK** `supplier_id`. Table `Supplier` has **FK** `country_id`. Table `Country` has two fields: `country_id` and `country_name`.
Tried to put SQL query to get `country_name` of current product but got an error "Invalid control source". How fix it?

SQL query:

```
SELECT Country.country_name FROM 
Country INNER JOIN 
(Supplier INNER JOIN Product ON Product.supplier_id=Supplier.supplier_id) 
ON Supplier.country_id=Country.country_id;
```

[image]

**Solved:**

Main `Form` has to have following query `SELECT * FROM (Country INNER JOIN Supplier ON Country.country_id = Supplier.country_id) INNER JOIN Product ON Supplier.supplier_id = Product.supplier_id;` in `Property sheet > Data > Record source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combo's Control Source property is the form's record source field to which you want to bind the combo.  So it sounds like the form's record source does not include a field named `country_name`.  (It doesn't matter here that the combo's Row Source does include that field --- you won't be binding the combo to it.)

On the combo's property sheet, click the drop-down arrow on the right side of the Control Source box.  It should display the names of all the fields it recognizes as included in the form's record source.

Comment: `country name` combo in properties does not have `country_name` in control source. My form has only `Product` as record source because it offers only one table to select.

Comment: Which field in `Product` is the one where you want to store the combo value?

Comment: I had to modify the form's record set in order to see for in `property sheet > control source` the field/column I need.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting field name in that query will be `country_name` (i.e., without the `Country.` prefix).  Just use `country_name` as your control source.

Comment: What's the form's record source?

Comment: It was table `Product`.